# Replace text with link in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, angular, contenteditable

I'm trying to implement an identification system like on facebook in my Angular 6 application. When a user write a comment(in a contenteditable div), he can press '@' key and then the name of the person he want to identify.

here is the html part:

```
<div contenteditable="true" (keyup)="onInputKeyUp($event)" id="commentInput"></div>
<div class="suggestion-list">
    <a *ngFor="let user of userSuggestions" (click)="selectUserSugg(user)">
        <div class="user-item">
            <div class="author-img">
                <img [src]="user.thumb" alt="author" title="author" />
            </div>
            <div class="author-name">{{user.firtName}} {{user.lastName}}</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the angular part:

```
selectUserSugg(user: any){
    console.log(user);
}
```

For now I'm able to read the name after the '@' key and send the request to find  the users that match.

Here is an example:

[image]

When user click on "John Lennon" I would like to replace "@John" by `<a href="/profile/johnlennon">John Lennon</a>`

How to manage this ?

Comment: may be using `innerHTML`, but it would be great if you show some code to us

Comment: @PardeepJain I have updated my question

Comment: can you create small stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a variable to "innerHTML", so that when `selectUserSugg(user)` function is called, it will append your desired output in "comments" variable.

```
<div contenteditable="true" (keyup)="onInputKeyUp($event)" id="commentInput" [innerHTML]="comments"></div>
```

The variable "comments" should be defined in your `.ts` file.
`[innerHTML]` will allow template to render HTML code from your variable.

This will solve your problem of having comment section with "content" and "link to user" both.

And for replacing "@John" by link, you can parse "comments" variable and use regex.